# Loading only Modified Component through Clearcase UCM Plugin + Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

My clearcase project has been configured with multiple components (20 components) , So when i tried to download the snapshot view from Jenkins it is downloading the whole code base for all the components which is nearly 10 GB.

But i don't need all the components to be downloaded so do we have any plugin or configuration to control this. Also once i downloaded the whole code first time i am trying to get the latest baseline code for second time which also takes more time. So i need some solution to get only the modified components.

Note : Clearcase team is maintaining only one baseline for all the components(Stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snapshot view only download what its loading rules tell it to.

You can check those rules with:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot/view
cleartool catcs
```

Do a `cleartool edcs` to edit those rules and load only the component you need.
Once you have done that, Jenkins, when using the same view, will only loads what you have specified.

Comment: Thanks i modified the view with only component which i need. But i need one more clarification- Whether i can download only required folder but not full code base from the component.Since i am trying to create the jar only with that code.

Comment: @Java_Sol Sure: your load rule does not have to stop at the vob level: load /avob/a/path/to/subfolder. But that will only work if that subfolder is selected by the select rules (which should be the case here)